# AJAX delete rails ... error: undefined local variable or method delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting an error on my attempt at an AJAX request for delete.

I think that it is from the html generator function in the view.

```
NameError in ProductsController#edit


undefined local variable or method `delete' for #<#<Class:0x000001071a0998>:0x00000108bb7bb0>
```

view

```
  <% @product.pictures.each do |p| %>
    <%= image_tag p.image.url(:medium) %>
    <%= link_to "Delete" , p, remote: true, method: delete %>
  <% end %>
```

route

```
resources :pictures, only: [:destroy]
```

coffeescript

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
      alert "The post was deleted."
```

picture controller

```
  def delete
    @picture = Picture.new(params[:user])
    @picture.destroy
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `method: :delete`. `delete` is not a method you can call.